# Create new data objects with a popup panel fails

Tags: jsf-2, dialog, richfaces

Here I am again with a JSF problem, this time it is more about richfaces (4.2.1 final, JSF 2). I have an eytended DataTable and want to add new items. There ist the List of `Journey`-objects, every attribute have getter and setter. The table is created well (there are already some items in the list). And now I click the "add new item" button:

```
<a4j:commandButton ajax="true" value="Neue Fahrt hinzufügen" 
   actionListener="'{editorBean.prepareCreateJourney}" render="createJourneyPopupForm"  
   oncomplete="#{rich:component('createJourneyPopup')}.show()" />
```

The editorBean is *SessionScoped*, the method is properply called and create a new object of `Journey` called `currentJourney`. A popup comes up and should allow me to insert some input:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="createJourneyPopup" modal="true">
    <h:panelGrid id="createJourneyPopupForm" columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel for="currentId" value="ID" />
        <h:inputText id="currentId"
            value="#{editorBean.currentJourney.journeyNumber}" />
        <rich:message for="currentId" />
        [...and more...]
    </h:panelGrid>

    <a4j:commandButton value="Save"
      execute="currentId currentTrainType operator">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{editorBean.doCreateJourney}"
            render=":vmsEditorForm:resultTable" />
        <rich:componentControl target="createJourneyPopup" operation="hide" />
    </a4j:commandButton>
    <a4j:commandButton value="Abbrechen"
        onclick="#{rich:component('createJourneyPopup')}.hide();" />
</rich:popupPanel>
```

When i clicked the button, the method `doCreateJourney` is called, but the `currentJourney` is empty. It is the default `Journey` object after creating it. No setter was called, do a hint on the inputfields.

I checked the names twice, there are getters and setters for alle needed objects. I tried to change the scope, but no effect. Objects are the same, in the prepare method i created `Journey(id=151)` and in the save method it is still `Journey(id=151)`.

What is going on here? I can't be this difficult to make some dialogs to create and edit data objects. Thank you for listening and for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap both your inputs and your commandButtons in a form in order to correctly submit the data.

```xml
<rich:popupPanel id="createJourneyPopup" modal="true">
    <h:form>
        ... the content of your popupPanel
    </h:form>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Regards,

Comment: Well, i looked here for the similar edit-dialog: http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&sample=dataTableEdit

And the popupPanel is in the same <h:form>. But your are right, it is right to create two forms and include the dialog outside the first <h:form>. And this is working! Thank you!